# forloop.index as a condition in an if-statement in shopify

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, shopify, liquid

**I'm trying to do something very simple.** I wrote:

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
   {{ if forloop.index = 1 }}
        Hello World!
   {{ endif }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Problem:**
"Hello World!" appears in every iteration.
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Looks like in each round of the loop, you're overwriting the index to always be equal to 1.  Try

```
{% if forloop.index == 1 %}
```

instead.

Comment: If you're looking for it to happen on the first iteration, you can try {{ if forloop.first }}

Comment: You should also change your {{ if }} etc to {% if %} and so forth.  Double braces are for output.

Comment: The example at http://wiki.shopify.com/Liquid#Tables looks vaguely similar to what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

So here again the **right version**, answering my own question... ;)

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
   {% if forloop.index == 1 %}
        Hello World!
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use native Liquid check

```
    
    {% for product in collection.products %}
        {% if forloop.first %}
            Hello World!
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```